# Add an associative array to an array - How to?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array structure, like this:

```
$families = array
(
    "Griffin"=>array
    (
        "Father" => "Peter",
        "Mother" => "Lois",
        "Child" => "Megan"
    ),

    "Brown"=>array
    (
        "Father" => "Cleveland",
        "Mother" => "Loretta",
        "Child" => "Junior"
    )

);
```

My question is:

How do I add another array called "Simpsons" to this structure with "Homer", "Marge" and "Bart" as the data?

Thanks guys....

Comment: how the previous elements were added? what have you tried?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$families['Simpsons'] = array(
  'Father' => 'Homer', 
  'Mother' => 'Marge', 
  'Child'  => 'Bart'
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Same way you added `Griffin` and Brown. If you do this later on in the code:

```
 $families['Simpsons'] = array('Mother' => 'Marge','Father' =>'Homer','Child' => 'Bart');
```